# ios delete row from table in ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I try to manage to delete a row from an `UITable` which is part on an `UIViewController`. I use the `Edit` button in the navigation bar. Hitting it will put the table rows in edit mode. But when a delete button in a row is pressed I get an error `...'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0….` when using the following:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSMutableArray *work_array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.inputValues];
        [work_array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

What do I miss here? The [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) documentation seems to be outdated somehow.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple. You are not updating your data model properly before deleting the row from the table.

All you do is create some new array and delete a row from that. That's pointless. You need to update the same array used by the other data source methods such as `numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: Hello rmaddy, Thanks for the hint. I just took the additional array out and changed it to my array I use in the data model. I was just too  sloppy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that you are not directly updating your table's data source. You first create a completely new array called work_array based on your data source (I'm assuming it's self.inputValues) and then you remove an item from it, and then try to delete a row, but your tableView's data source still contains the item you intended to remove.

All you need to do is ensure that self.inputValues is a mutable array and directly remove the object at the index for that array, like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.inputValues removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer I found my mistake with rmaddys hint. Thanks anyway!